# WheelDown not sending the correct number of actual wheel scrolls

Tags: autohotkey

I have a little problem: the below AHK script works in principle and sends "i" when the mouse wheel is scrolled down. Just the number of "i"s doesn't correspond to the length of the mouse wheel scrolling — it should be more than just one (or just a few for a wide scroll):

```
!WheelDown::         ;! is equal to Alt in AHK hotkeys, so this is Alt + WheelDown
Send i               ;This should send (write) from just one "i" (for a single mouse wheel scrolling) to as many times "i" as the mouse wheel is scrolled (not just one no matter how long the wheel move!)
return               ;This ends the function of the hotkey, it can be used repeatedly though
```

Looking forward to your answers and hitting the "resolved"-button ;-)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and on my side, it sends multiple letters "i" when the mouse wheel is scrolled down. On your side, it might be an issue with latency, try to add sleep command in your script to test out the problem, something like `Sleep, 30`.

Comment: @akshif: thank you, when I wanted to implement your code line I tested my original code again and now it produces the expected number of "i"s — probably depending on computer workload (although I couldn't say why in my case)!? If it happens again I'll test your sleep-option, thanks again. In the meantime, any other suggestions are also still very welcome :-)

Comment: The script should work fine as is... A couple of questions though: 1. Have you tried different mice? 2. Do you have any other mouse software in use (such as EitherMouse)? 3. What program(s) are you testing this with?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works perfectly for me:

```
#NoEnv
!WheelDown::
Send i
return
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks, will try it. I wanted to test it right away with MsgBox, but it only opens one single box, not as many as there were scrolls and other appropriate output options like 'print' or 'echo' seem to be missing in AHK, too. If you know one I could test your code and mark your answer as the solution earlier?